# Error trying to center a view using VFL with Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to center a view within its superview using VFL, this is my code:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // THE SUPERVIEW 
    UIView *sectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_W, [self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section])];
    sectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    // THE LABEL TO BE CENTERED
    UILabel *sectionTitle = [UILabel new];
    sectionTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    sectionTitle.Text = @"Generals";
    [sectionView addSubview:sectionTitle];

    // AUTOLAYOUT INFO 
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"label":sectionTitle, @"view":sectionView};
    NSArray *leftPosition = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[view]-[label]"
                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];

    [sectionView addConstraints:leftPosition];

    return sectionView;
}
```

Using this code I get this error

```
2014-06-20 09:44:20.938 gogo[442:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[NSLayoutConstraint constant], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-1047.25/Layout.subproj/NSLayoutConstraint.m:601
2014-06-20 09:44:24.651 gogo[442:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(null)'
```

If I change the VFL using just `"|"` instead of `"view"` to refer to the superview I don't get any error but the vertical alignment doesn't work.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
...

[sectionView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: sectionTitle
                                                        attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem: sectionView
                                                        attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                       multiplier: 1.0f
                                                         constant: 0.0f]];
}
```

EDIT:

Tried this, and UILabel is automatic centered Y:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// THE LABEL TO BE CENTERED
     UILabel *sectionTitle = [UILabel new];
     sectionTitle.Text = @"Generals";
     return sectionTitle;
}
```

Comment: Same error... I suppose that the problem is the superview has not a center when I try to get it from AutoLayout.